# How to order 2 related tables in one query having order fields both of them

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, the first one is ITEMS and the other is GALLERY (where I have the images of every item), these 2 tables are related by item_id = item_gal_id.

In these 2 tables there are 2 important fields, item_order (in ITEMS) and img_order (in GALLERY) which I use to order the items and the images by drag & drop.

I have no problem to order and output the items in the home page with this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM items a 
LEFT JOIN gallery b ON (a.item_id = b.item_gal_id) 
WHERE a.it_public='SI' 
GROUP BY a.item_id, b.item_gal_id 
ORDER BY a.item_order ASC
```

BUT...every item shows 1 (ONE) image in the home page and that image is not the one suposed to be, I mean that I can't output the image that is in the first place of the GALLERY order...

When I hit in one of the items to go to the detail page is easy to show the images in the order I want by using this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM gallery 
WHERE item_gal_id = (the item_id I send by GET) 
ORDER BY img_order ASC
```

So, how can I show a list of items ordered by item_order and, in the same query, to show the image that is the first for that item having img_order, is there a way to do this?

I've been searching and reading for 2 days with no luck, trying several options but I'm really stack with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the to pull out the minimum `item_gal_id` for each `item`, then you can use a simple `JOIN` with aggregation. This requires you to explicitly list the columns from `items` that you want to display (I assumed `item_id`, `col1` and `col2`).

```
SELECT i.item_id, i.col1, i.col2, MIN(g.item_gal_id)
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN gallery g ON i.item_id = g.item_gal_id
WHERE i.it_public = 'SI' 
GROUP BY i.item_id, i.col1, i.col2
ORDER BY i.item_order
```

If you need more information from `gallery` than just `item_gal_id`, then one solution would be to use window function `ROW_NUMBER()` (available in MySQL 8.0 only):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        i.item_id,
        i.item_order,
        i.col1, 
        i.col2, 
        g.item_gal_id, 
        g.col3, 
        g.col4,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY i.item_id ORDER BY g.item_gal_id) rn
    FROM items i
    LEFT JOIN gallery g ON i.item_id = g.item_gal_id
    WHERE i.it_public = 'SI' 
) x 
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY item_order
```

---

*Edit*: based on the comments, here is another option without window functions, using a correlated subquery with a `NOT EXITS` condition to filter on the gallery record that has the lowest `img_order`.

```
SELECT i.*, g.*
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN gallery g ON i.item_id = g.item_gal_id
WHERE 
    i.it_public = 'SI' 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM gallery g1 
        WHERE i.item_id = g1.item_gal_id AND g1.img_order < g.img_order
    )
ORDER BY i.item_order
```

Comment: Hi GMB, thanks, my server does not use MYSQL 8, so I have to solve it the old school way. But I CAN join the 2 tables and I get the correspondant image for every item, the problem is that I want to show the FIRST image of gallery for that item when I have 5 or more images. Lets suppose item 001 has 3 images and the order of those images is image1 (order 3), image2 (order 1) and image1 (order 2). So when I display all the items, item 001 must show image2 which has order 1 in gallery table.

Comment: Not really, I just need more from gallery like the image and the order of that image (, g.thumb_name, g.img_order).

Comment: @Walter: OK, I updated my answer with another query, that might respond to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery instead:

```
SELECT i.*,
       (SELECT g.item_gal_id
        FROM gallery g
        WHERE g.item_gal_id = i.item_id
        ORDER BY g.item_gal_id
        LIMIT 1
       ) as item_gal_id
FROM items i 
WHERE i.it_public = 'SI'
ORDER BY i.item_order ASC;
```

If you need additional columns from `gallery`, use this as a subquery and join `gallery` back in.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your answer, I'm having this error: 

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.item_gal_id FROM items i WHERE i.it_public = 'SI' ORDER BY i.item_order ASC LIM' at line 1